# How can I compute the estimated installation time for an MSI file?

Tags: windows-installer

I want to write a program in C# to get the estimated installation time of MSI. For example, when MSI installation starts, the code will get the estimated installation time i.e. 30 sec and when installation finish the time should be 0.

Comment: This.. is a way too broad

Comment: IF you can provide me little bit of implementation details. that will be great help. I will write the code by myself.

Comment: It's nothing to do with code or implementation. Even Windows can't predict how long it will take. You should add some more detail, such as if you are Installing the MSI in silent mode, whether you intend to show a progress bar.

Comment: Yes, i will install the MSI in silent mode and no progress bar (kind of console application).